# How to have dynamic height in CustomMultiChildLayout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I created a `CustomMultiChildLayout` in order to customize the positions of its children. Then tried to put `CustomMultiChildLayout` into a `Container`, with `BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 500)`, then the `CustomMultiChildLayout` has always the maxHeight 500 as height. It cannot adjust its height according to its children.

So how can I have dynamic height for my `CustomMultiChildLayout`? If this is not possible, are there any other ways to implement this layout?

**Background:**

I defined 3 widgets, each of them is a `Container`, and I need to customize their positions.

SellerWidget should be positioned in the middle of two other widgets.

Please refer to this image: [image]

Here's my code:

```
class ProductComboWidget extends StatelessWidget {

    final Product _product;

    ProductComboWidget(this._product);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 500),
            child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
                delegate: _TitleInfoLayout(),
                children: <Widget>[
                    LayoutId(
                        id: _TitleInfoLayout.title,
                        child: ProductTitleWidget(_product)
                    ),
                    LayoutId(
                        id: _TitleInfoLayout.info,
                        child: ProductInfoWidget(_product)
                    ),
                    LayoutId(
                        id: _TitleInfoLayout.seller,
                        child: SellerWidget(_product.seller)
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        );
    }

}

class _TitleInfoLayout extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {

    static const String title = 'title';
    static const String info = 'info';
    static const String seller = 'seller';

    @override
    void performLayout(Size size) {
        final Size titleSize = layoutChild(title, BoxConstraints(maxWidth: size.width));
        positionChild(title, Offset(0, 0));

        layoutChild(info, BoxConstraints(maxWidth: size.width));
        positionChild(info, Offset(0, titleSize.height));

        final Size sellerSize = layoutChild(seller, BoxConstraints());
        positionChild(seller, Offset(size.width - sellerSize.width - 20, titleSize.height - sellerSize.height / 2));
    }

    @override
    bool shouldRelayout(MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Actual result:**

The height of `CustomMultiChildLayout` always equals to BoxConstraint.maxHeight, it cannot adjust its height according to its children.

Please refer to this image: [image]

There is a useless empty space on the bottom of this widget.

**Expected result:**

Have its height adapted to its children, like other widgets.

Comment: the size of the parent cannot depend on the sizes of the children. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html

Comment: I think it's lot easier to achieve what you are trying to do with just Rows and Culomns.

Comment: Just in case, there's a package that may be handy for this kind of needs: _**[boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy)**_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspired by the implementation of `Column` and `Stack`, I created a custom layout to do this job. https://gist.github.com/jxw1102/a9b58a78a80c8e2f54233b418429fa50

Comment: Does not work for new non-nullable Flutter. Also `RenderCustomLayoutBox` expects to take a list of `RenderBox`.

Comment: @MichałDobiDobrzański I added an update for a nullable version in the link.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SingleChildScrollView` as parent to get the dynamic height of parent as per the number of child widgets.

Comment: This doesn't work.
`flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():`
`flutter: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.`
`flutter: This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put`
`flutter: inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.`